# The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in /dev/nvme0n1p1 at /boot/efi failed

Tags: boot, partitioning, installation, debian

Trying to install Debian dual boot with windows 10 on SSD but I have this error message : `The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in /dev/nvme0n1p1 at /boot/efi failed` I forced EFI installation, encrypted my / so I had to make a ext4 primary /boot partition (p4) and a primary EFI ESP partition (p1)

Any idea what this could be all about ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Ubuntu. I reformatted my partitions. After I reformatted my main partition I was able to install Ubuntu. I guess try reformatting all the partitions manually. **The file system may be corrupted or encrypted. My file system was encrypted from a prior installation of Ubuntu.**

On Ubuntu I reformatted my main partition with ext4.

Went into terminal with `ctrl` `alt` `f1`

Then logged in as root `sudo su`

Then formatted the partition

```
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda2
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: View edit -> "The file system may be corrupted or encrypted. My file system was encrypted from a prior installation of Ubuntu."